# Windows 10 Virtual Machine from Microsoft?

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, download, microsoft

Microsoft offers a free to download virtual machine for Windows 11 [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/virtual-machines/)

But I am looking for a Windows 10 virtual machine.  Does Microsoft offer (or previously offered) such a download?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the past I was able to find some using archive.org for [old versions of that page](https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/virtual-machines/)
Like this: https://web.archive.org/web/20200612045637/https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/virtual-machines/

The links to the VM images from microsoft still work.

Here is one: https://download.microsoft.com/download/b/7/a/b7a6fb6e-cae1-4e19-9249-205803bc4ada/WinDev2004Eval.VMware.zip (i think?)

Comment: But do those VMs (even if you get the download, which you could) still work? Microsoft writes on those pages that those VMs are supposed to expire after a specific date.

Comment: @YisroelTech Does expire simply mean you get an error message/nag saying "unlicensed" etc, or does it mean, doesn't work?

Comment: On the current page it says "*If the evaluation period expires, the desktop background will turn black, you will see a persistent desktop notification indicating that the system is not genuine, and the PC will shut down every hour*"

Comment: @PeterM - These VMs are unlicensed copies of Windows. Windows is NOT free software, these VMs are provided, as a way to encourage the Windows ecosystem. Microsoft no longer provides Windows 10 developer VMs at this time, any VM you did happen to find, likely would already be expired. If you want a Windows 10 VM you’ll have to create it yourself and purchase a license (which again will be difficult since those are no longer on sale by Microsoft).

Comment: @Ramhound I know the licensing status/restrictions of these VMs.  I'm also trying to debug a software installation on Win10.  You can still download a Win 10 ISO, and installed it sans license.  But my software installation actually crashed the Win10 VM (and also the Win 11 VM from MS).  Amusingly the Win 10 VM mentioned above fails to start because it thinks I don't have a 64 bit processor, even though I am running an i5-1340P

Comment: @PeterM - Sounds like you don’t have hardware virtualization enabled. You asked about the expiration, now your problem has nothing to do with the expiration status of the VM since it’s not even getting to that stage, but if you did the system wouldn’t be usable. Why don’t you create your own VM with the appropriate version of Windows 10 on it and NOT use these trial VMs?

Comment: @Ramhound Except that I have been running multiple other VMs this morning on the same system.  But as per the comment from Yisroel, the I believe that the system will still usable (at least for what I want to test)

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to follow the instructions at https://www.extremetech.com/computing/198427-how-to-install-windows-10-in-a-virtual-machine to create your own Windows 10 VM.

From that article, I went to https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10 which allowed me, using an existing Windows machine, to download the Windows 10 installation media creation tool.

Using that tool, I created an ISO file to create a VM with.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).